# images in multiple row instead of one row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My problem [Want the remaining photos in the second row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vfat.jpg)

**Link for the example image **

I am having trouble with a row of overflow images, which is in div "small-img-row".

The small-img-row is under the col-2 which is the main image.

My question is how to make the overflow images to be in the second row.

such as [this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnCrB.png) 
(I am still learning html and css )

```
<div class="small-container">

<div class="col-2">
    <img src="src/0File .JPG" alt="" width="800%" id="product-img">
    <div class="small-img-row">
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/0File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/1File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/2File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/3File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/4File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/5File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/6File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/7File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/8File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/9File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/10File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/11File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/12File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/13File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/14File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="src/15File .JPG" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="single-product-page-text">
</div>
```

```
.small-img-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: auto;
}
div.discription-txt {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
}
.col-2 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.col-2 {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.small-img-row img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/* the sub image size  */
.small-img-col img {
    min-width: 120px;
    width: 20%;
    size: 100%;
    padding: 6px;
}
.small-container {
    padding: 1%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I would suppose by adding flex wrap to "small-img-row" will help you achieve what you want? Anyway, have a look at this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex-wrap: wrap` is the solution. I have adjusted the rest of CSS accordingly.

Please refer to the code snippet below.

```css
.col-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col-2>img{
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

.small-img-row img{
  max-width: 150px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.small-img-row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
  margin-right: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-container">

<div class="col-2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="800%" id="product-img">
    <div class="small-img-row">
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
        <div class="small-img-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="" width="100%" class="small-img"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="single-product-page-text">
</div>
```

Comment: right thanks, there was something I am confused with "col-2", it seems like it has limitation on spacing if i use col-2, and once I change the class name, everything works out great.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 1:

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/dyXQoRd?editors=1100

There are few changes I made in your code, like modified the max-width for the image tag to 120px so it won't exceed more than that (without removing the surrounding divs)

---

You need to add

```css
.small-img-row {
  .
  .
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

so that the smaller images will be wrapped to the next line.

Also remove flex settings/properties for selector `.small-img-row img`
It should exist for the parent which is the actual flex container.
Always remember, flex should be applied to the parent elements not the child elements. In your case `.small-img-row` is your parent element.

Comment: thank, but now the images are lined up vertically instead.

Comment: Yes its because you have wrapped the img tag using div tag, and by default div covers 100% width. If you remove the surrounding div tag it should work. Also you need to remove the max-width from the image style.

Comment: I have added the codepen link in my answer, please check, it completes your need.